# xamarin android how generate image with a string

Tags: image, xamarin.android

we have an xamarin android app who call an API who send a QRCode as a string
Look the print screen i join, here is it what i receive after the call to the api ..

Now i would like to transform this string into a image but i can't.

Someone has idea how to transform this string into an image ?!
thanks
[image: here is it the return of ws, property qrCode is the string who represents a qrcode]

Comment: According to your description, you call api to convert QRCode to string, then you want to convert string to QRCode back?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve, we return a byte[] and with this we can display image